# Sum based on Value in an Array

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I would like to do a simulation in Excel 1,000 times and then sum up the number of successes for each trial. I would like to change the trial size for run.

For example, I have 1,000 numbers ranging from `0` - `31` in a column in Excel. Lets say the first three numbers are `28`, `31`, `27`. For the first run, I would like to run a random number generator 28 times and then sum up how many of the values are less than `.277`. The next column would have 31 trials, and the next would have 27 and so on until all 1,000 numbers are used in order.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
For i = 1 To 1001
For j = 1 To iCol.Value
    Range("A" & j) = Rnd()
    If Cells(j, 1).Value < 0.277 Then
    Cells(j, i) = 1
    Else
    Cells(j, i) = 0
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem I am having is with the `For j = 1 To iCol.Value`. If it was a set number `i` would do `j = 1 to 34` but I want it to change with each run based on the values in a different column.

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  If I'm understanding this, you are wanting to run a series of tests 1000 times.  Each series can be 0-31 cycles of the same test, and you have those cycle-counts stored in a column.  It looks like what you set out to do is use another sheet to store all the random numbers in one column, and the results in the rest.  That's a LOT of columns!

Unless you really need to store all those 1's and 0's long term, you can use another variable to do the counting and skip writing the values to a cell at all  until you have the result... the number of times your statement solved true.

You could do something like this (you'll probably have to change a reference or two since I can't see your workbook)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
'Some new variables/objects
Dim lCurrentCount As Long
Dim iCol
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Set this to the source sheet (where your trial counts are)
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

'This will be used to keep track of how many times the test
'was true without using the cells/columns to store data
lCurrentCount = 0

For i = 1 To 1000
'This is what will incriment you to the next row to get a new trial count
iCol = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    For j = 1 To iCol
        If Rnd() < 0.277 Then
            'If it's true, add one to the current count
            'If not go to the next
            lCurrentCount = lCurrentCount + 1
        End If
        If j = iCol Then
            'If this is the last one in a trial, put the
            'True count next to the cycle number
            Range("B" & i) = lCurrentCount
            lCurrentCount = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

If however you really need to keep all those individual results, it's still the same basic idea.  You need a cell or range object that you can use to increment your source row along with your for loops.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Some new variables/objects
Dim iCol As Long
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

'Set this to the source sheet (where your trial counts are)
Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
'Set this to the target sheet (where your trial Results will go)
Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = 1 To 100
'This is what will incriment you to the next row to get a new trial count
'Using i in the cells reference to what I assume is another sheet
iCol = wsSource.Cells(i, 1)
For j = 1 To iCol
    wsTarget.Range("A" & j) = Rnd()
    If wsTarget.Cells(j, 1).Value < 0.277 Then
    wsTarget.Cells(j, i) = 1
    Else
    wsTarget.Cells(j, i) = 0
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Looks like some fun science, hope it helps!

Comment: Glad to help. You had a good start, just missing those last two pieces.  Best of luck!